# How to process each interface differently on a mail server

Tags: sendmail, exim

I am running number of web servers on google cloud platform. Google cloud bans port 25 to prevent spam, so to receive mails I use different server which forwards all mail to a google server on a different port, using router

```
redir:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = *
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = * myhost.com::2567
```

Now if I want to use multiple interfaces and redirect each interface to a different server, do I have to run multiple instances of exim or is there a way to just configure single exim (or any other server) in a way that would use different routes for different interfaces?

Something like

```
redir:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = *
  interface = 1.1.1.1
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = * myhost1.com::2567

redir:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = *
  interface = 1.1.1.2
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list = * myhost2.com::2567
```

Comment: You probably want virtual domains. No need to use multiple addresses/interfaces. At least postfix supports the functionality; I think exim too, but I am not so sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to choose interface in the transport

eg, choose randomly:

```
  transport = ${listextract{${eval:1+${randint:2}}}{<;1.1.1.1;1.1.1.2}}
```